# Get Value of Span Element that was changed before by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows-desktop-gadgets

i am developing a gadget and i am using JavaScript to change innerHTML of span, but after some operations i need to read that value. Additionally i am using pre-entered value for spans but when i try to read new data function loads pre-entered one.
Is there any solution for that?

**JS:**

```
function read_write(condition,filename){
    var fso  = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
    var fh = fso.OpenTextFile(System.Gadget.path+'\\'+filename+'.txt',condition, true,-2);
    if (condition == 1) {
    var result = fh.ReadLine();
    return result;      
    } 
    else if (condition == 2) {
    var spn1 = document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML;
    fh.WriteLine(spn1+','+document.getElementById('span2').innerHTML);
    }
    fh.Close();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="sonuc">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:50%" valign="top">
        <span class="result" id="span1"></span><br/>
        <span class="result" id="span2"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you're trying to do?  What type of gadget are you developing - Google Gadget, Windows Gadget, etc.

Comment: @Alper .. for now you question doesn't make any sense ..maybe sharing some code would help

Comment: I am sorry for insufficient information. I am trying to coding a Vista/7 Sidebar Gadget and trying to write a function for saving values to harddisk.
Function:
function read_write(){
var fso  = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
var fh = fso.OpenTextFile(System.Gadget.path+'\\fl.txt',2, true,-2);
var spn1 = document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML;
fh.WriteLine(spn1+','+document.getElementById('span2').innerHTML);
}
fh.Close();
}

I used spn1 variable to try if using variable works...
Thanks to everyone..

Comment: HTML part of coding is:
<table id="sonuc">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td style="width:50%" valign="top"><span class="result" id="span1"></span><br/><span class="result" id="span2"></span></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

Comment: @Alper: I've added your code to the question.  There's a syntax error in your code (an extra `}` just before `fh.Close()`), I left it in because I thought something might be missing from what you've pasted.  If so, you can edit it using the link right underneath the question tags.

Comment: @Andy E: Yes i've not written all the function because unwritten part is just about reading, so i corrected the code part. Still problem is continued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using innerHTML to write to the span element, you should be able to use it again to read. How are you trying to read until now?

Comment: I am using 
document.getElementById('span1').innerHTML = data[0];
to change inner part of span
as you can guess, data is an array of some values...